# Where the Http404 and PermissionDenied are handled exactly in django?

Tags: django, django-views

Where and how do the Http404 or PermissionDenied are handled exactly in django? I could not find functions or methods to catch these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

inside urls.py add these lines:

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
handler500 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_error_view'
handler403 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_permission_denied_view'
handler400 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_bad_request_view'
```